# Linked list ( in C ) why does this not work

Tags: c, linked-list

i am trying to build a program that creates an automata state ( his symbols + the next state ) & displays the states

So here's my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>



typedef struct State
{
int state;
char symb;
int newState;

struct State *next;
}State;

State *head,*neww,*p;


void Add()
{
  int i,j;

  printf("How many transitions in your automata\n");
  scanf("%d",&j);
  for(i=0;i<j;i++)
  {
  if(neww!=NULL)
  {
      neww = (struct State *)malloc(sizeof (struct State));
      printf("State number:");
      scanf("%d",&neww->state);
      printf("With which symbole to the next state:");
      scanf(" %c",&neww->symb);
      printf("To which state :");
      scanf("%d",&neww->newState);
      neww->next=NULL;

      if(head==NULL)
      {
          head=neww;
      }
      else{
        p = head;
        while(p->next !=NULL)
        {
            p=p->next;
        }
        p->next = neww;
      }
  }
  }
}

void Display()
{
    p=head;

    while(p != NULL)
    {
        printf("State : %d to state : %d with symbole : %c \n\n",p->state,p->newState,p->symb);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("END\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    head = NULL;

    Add();
    Display();
    return 0;
}
```

Can you please help me figure out why it stops working after the 1st printf ?

EDIT1 : Now it stops after the 2nd printf after changing scanf("%d",j) to &j

EDIT2 : After correcting all the scanfs it works fine !

EDIT3 : I added the corrections to the code , now i have a loop in the display it keeps displaying the states without stopping i guess it's a link problem

EDIT4 : The loop in the display was due to non-allocating the space for the others states ; i will add the corrections to the code

Thanks for the help

Comment: scanf used incorrectly, should be `scanf("%d", &j)`. this invokes UB. there is the same problem with your other scanf calls

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply , i corrected that one !
Now it stops working after the second printf

Comment: i still can't find why there's a loop in the display , the linking in the Add fct seems to be good so does the while condition in the display so i don't understand Thanks for the help

Comment: if you arent handling cycles in the display then you could enter an infinite loop..

Comment: I just found the mistake , i was creating space only for the first state ; now i moved the malloc inside the loop and everything works fine !

Comment: init head global variable to NULL, and correct this &neww->state and similar to this  &(neww->state) and so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your code. You have not read the transition, state number and other variables. Just correct the syntax of `scanf` through out the program and everything else will work fine. Add an `&` before the variable in `scanf`.

Comment: Thank you i didn't realize i made the same mistake in all the scanf ! it works just fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

correct this in add() function:

```
neww = malloc(sizeof (struct State)); // alloc
if(neww!=NULL){ // then test
```

**Explanation:**

- You first had to attempt to allocate new state using malloc():

  - On success, malloc() returns a pointer to allocated memory,
  - On failure it returns NULL;
- Thus it comes if(neww!=NULL){ } to test if the block of memory has been successfully allocated.
- Write on that block only on success.

Comment: Please provide more explanation about how this solves the issue. It is a very low quality post

Comment: you first had to attempt to allocate new state using malloc(), malloc() on success returns a pointer to allocated memory, on failure it returns NULL; thus it comes `if(neww!=NULL){` to test if the block of memory has been successfully allocated. and write on that block only on success.

Answer (score 0):

Remarque: char may causes headache when using scanf()!

when you pass address of a member within  struct to scanf think to enclose that member by brackets like so:

```
scanf("%d",&(neww->state));
```

the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


typedef struct State State;
struct State
{
    int     state;
    char    symb; // <- char is problematic with scanf
    int     newState;
    State   *next;
};

State *head=NULL, // !MPORTANT: Initialized to NULL 
      *p;
/*_______________________________________________________________
*/
void Add(void){
    int i,j;
    State *neww;

    printf("\nHow many transitions in your automata? ");
    scanf("%d",&j);

    for(i=0;i<j;i++){
        //use calloc to initialize memory to 0
        neww = calloc(1,sizeof (struct State));
        if(neww!=NULL){ // only if calloc() succeded

            printf("State number: ");
            scanf("%d",&(neww->state)); // the addres of state not neww

            printf("With which symbole to the next state: ");
            scanf(" %c",&(neww->symb)); // idem @ of (symb)


            printf("To which state: ");
            scanf("%d",&(neww->newState)); // and idem @ of (newState)

            //neww->next=NULL; already been initialized by calloc

            if(head==NULL){
                head=neww;
            }else{
                p = head;
                while(p->next !=NULL){
                    p=p->next;
                }
                p->next = neww;
            }
        }else{
            perror("no enough memory");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
/*_______________________________________________________________
*/
void Display(void){

    p=head;
    printf("\n\nLIST\n");
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        printf("State : %d to state : %d with symbole : %c \n\n",p->state,p->newState,p->symb);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("END\n");
}
/*_______________________________________________________________
*/
int main(void){
    Add();
    Display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advices!
It will be very helpful for the next codes.